# Как отличить двойной клик мыши от одного?

Tags: java, javafx

Появилась задача сделать обработку Double click и Click по ячейке `TableView` в `JavaFx`.
Распознать двойной клик я могу с помощью`getClicklCount == 2` или используя время с предыдущего нажатия что-то типо

```
if(firstClick - System.currentTimeMillis() < 300){
//Double click
}
else{
//single click
}
```

Но когда срабатывает Double click тогда срабатывает и single. Как отделить их выполнение, чтобы ветка single не работала вместе с Double.
Видел примеры на англоязычном stackoverflow, но я их не понял, можете разжевать пожалуйста, а то уйму времени занимаюсь этой задачей.

P.S уже хотел после клика запускать таймер и ждать 0.3с, проверяя будет ли еще один клик в течении этого времени, но понимаю, что в дебри залезу и запутаюсь в коде.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949461/javafx-2-click-and-double-click

Comment: По идее не нужно проверять время между кликами, достаточно `getClickCount()`. Если второй раз срабатывает, попробуйте `mouseEvent.consume();` делать.

Comment: @insolor, а можете объяснить как работает `consume`. Видел, что его много где используют, но русской документации по нему я не видел, а английскую к сожалению не понял, слишком мало информации по этому поводу нашел

Comment: Это "поглощение" (если буквально переводить) события, чтобы оно не обрабатывалось другими обработчиками (например, нажатие на кнопку обработалось только обработчиком контрола, но не обработчиками панелей и окна, где этот контрол находится).

Comment: По идее да, так

Comment: @insolor, если типо того
`if(mouseEvent.getClickCount()==2){
   System.out.println("double");
   mouseEvent.consume();
   }
else{
   System.out.println("single");
 }`
Править комментарии я не умею) Вот такой код не срабатывает

Comment: Не срабатывает - лишний одинарный клик происходит? Может у вас кнопка мыши просто двоит?

Comment: @insolor, при нажатии один раз выводит `single`, при двойном клике `single double`
То есть сначала срабатывает один клик, а затем и двойной

Comment: А обработчик как привязываете?

Comment: `this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {здесь выше написанный код}`
в методе `updateItem`
Наследую от `TableCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь, реализовал вот так

```
PauseTransition singlePressPause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(300));
                singlePressPause.setOnFinished(e -> {
                    //Code for sinlge click
                });

                this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {
                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        singlePressPause.play();
                    }
                    else if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        singlePressPause.stop();
                        //Code for Double click
                    }
```